# Alternative approaches to designing workflows for simple approval process in SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2013

I have to develop a simple document approval workflow in my SP 2013 on-premises site collection.
Instead of going with designer workflow, visual studio sequential workflow,can i implement this approach using visual web part?

i will create a  approver form using visual web part and have all the metadata from the document library of that particular item.

`page_load` && `if(!ispotback)` event will load the infor. about the particular document.

form is having approve, reject buttons and  it will update the status in a separate list.

Will this approach feasible? if its feasible how to get the exact document id, url, metadata on this approver's page load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the tools the platform gives you. This is built in functionality on libraries. Go to your library settings and click on Versioning settings. Enable content approval.

Now click on Workflow Settings. Then click Add a workflow. Configure a  *Approval - SharePoint 2010 workflow as desired, also ensure you tick the box to "Start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item."

Comment: But,can i assign a task to a specific group? will i get option to mention this sp group name anywhere , if i implement these steps?

Comment: my document library resides in a sub site and each sub site is different and its approvers are different.

Comment: After clicking next on the first page, you get to the task options where you can specify a group. If this is a manually initiated process, then this becomes a template the users can customize. If it is a on creation/on edit, then it uses the values you specify without allowing the user to alter it when initiated.

Comment: would like to know why my question is down voted.

Comment: Not sure, must have been a drive by downvote